# Mac Mini mid 2011 random reboot

Tags: mac-mini

I bought a Mac Mini mid 2011 and sometimes i have an hard reboot. I thought it was a power problem and I replaced it but nothing seems to have changed.

If i execute `log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 1h` the result is `kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -128`

I searched online but i cannot find anything.

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/ says it's a memory issue. Try running AHT, press & hold D at boot, run the short & full tests [may take a long time] & let us know what it reports. Also, if you see errors or crashes,  test by stripping all except one RAM stick & repeat with a different stick until you find which is failing.

Comment: I had also seen that page, but on some sites I also found that it was related to the GPU. I have to try a couple of banks that I have aside. I tried to start the AHT but it doesn't seem to start. Could it be because Catalina is there?

Comment: Catalina shouldn't be the issue on an older Mac without a T chip. Maybe see https://osxdaily.com/2016/06/25/how-to-use-apple-hardware-test-to-diagnose-mac-problems/ for more info.

Comment: I tried to run AHT but it restarted during the tests

Comment: Ram checked, usb checked (i need to try with bluetooth keyboard), thermal paste replaced but the result is the same: reboot and shutdown cause -128.
Sometimes after this reboot the screen still black and the fan is loudly

Comment: could it be the fan that is shorting? I read a little online that sometimes the temperature sensor is in the fan